# Learning index of "for-in loop"

Tags: python

I have a list and it contains lists. The inner lists are may be empty. This is the structure:

```
[[],[a,b],[],[c],[d]]
```

My code:

```
for inner in list:
   for char in inner:
      print char           # I want to add indexes of inner lists here
```

Output is:

```
abcd
```

I want the output to be:

```
2a2b4c5d
```

The numbers are indexes of inner lists. Is there quick way to do this?

Comment: You need quotes around the inner list items unless they really are variables. Also list is poor choice for a name.

Comment: Yes, there are quotes. I just forgot while writing here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please note that you should not use `list` as a variable name, since it `shadows` the built-in `list` type.

```
>>> lst = [[],['a','b'],[],['c'],['d']]
>>> for idx, inner in enumerate(lst):
      for char in inner:
        print idx, char


1 a
1 b
3 c
4 d
```

you see that `enumerate()` counts zero-based. you can specify a second argument as start though, to match your one-based expected output:

```
>>> for idx, inner in enumerate(lst, 1):
    for char in inner:
        print idx, char


2 a
2 b
4 c
5 d
```

but only do that if neccessary, python counts  0-based by convention.

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly that output, one way would be to write directly to sys.stdout.  The print command (in 2.x) would at best end up leaving spaces between each index + char.

```
import sys
for ndx, inner in enumerate([[],['a','b'],[],['c'],['d']], 1):
    for char in inner:
        sys.stdout.write('%d%s' % (ndx, char))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, inner in enumerate(myList):  # just add an index variable here
    for char in inner:
        print i          # and use it wherever you need to
        print char
```

Comment: This will give "ValueError: need more than one value to unpack".  You need to use enumerate as shown in ch3ka's answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for char in list[i]:
        print i+1
        print char
```

(three new answers appeared while typing this o.O)